# Modify the components of the main class through another class

Tags: vb.net, winforms, class

We have a school project and I'm trying to break our code into groups. I set my FormBorderStyle to None so I can modify it. But can I use another class to modify the components I have in my main?
An example would be:

```
Public Class main
    Private Sub btn_title_bar_exit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_title_bar_exit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btn_title_bar_minimize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_title_bar_minimize.Click
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class user_interface
    'Modify components and the form through here
    'example: btn_exit.ForeColor = Color.Black 
    'example: Me.Close()
End Class
```

*Also wondering, this a good way to break code?*

Comment: Question you have to ask yourself is, what's the justification of doing this? Are you trying to separate out formatting and presentation logic from the main form code? You *can* do this assuming the control properties are made public (which I think they are by default in WinForms), you just need to pass an instance of the form into your `user_interface` class. Still, you could just make the formatting code part of the main form - it depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: You might have heard of MVVM, this is how modern technologies such as WPF/Silverlight etc separate out presentation and formatting code from business logic, but it's probably not as easy to do in WinForms as the WPF binding mechanism is the perfect "glue" to link the presentation to the logic layer in MVVM

Comment: How could i pass the instances?

Comment: Just create an instance or static function which takes an argument of type `main` on the class - the question is, where are you going to call it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to separate routines (functions/methods/variables declarations...) because you have loads of code filling your class file, just use :

1) the `Partial` keyword

```
Public Partial Class MainClass
    ' MAIN CONTENT

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponents()
        ' ...
    End Sub

    ' ...
End Class
```

and in another file :

```
Public Partial Class MainClass
    ' USER INTERFACE HANDLERS...

    'Modify components and the form through here
    'example: btn_exit.ForeColor = Color.Black 
    'example: Me.Close()

    ' ...
End Class
```

So this is **the same Class**, and other classes may NOT be able to access/modify its members.

2) or either use `#Region` to split your code and group them :

```
Public Class MainClass

    #Region "Instanciation..."
    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponents()
        ' ...
    End Sub
    #End Region

    #Region "User Interface..."
        'Modify components and the form through here
        'example: btn_exit.ForeColor = Color.Black 
        'example: Me.Close()
        Public Sub btn1_Click(...)
        Public Sub Picture1_MouseMove(...)
    #End Region

    #Region "Public Properties..."
    '...
    #End Region

End Class
```

Then use the plus/minus to unfold/fold that part of the code.

---

If you *really* want to edit the members of your `MainClass` from another class, say, `RemoteClass`, there are **TONs** of way doing it, and it depends on what **exactly** you want to do.

You could make everything **`Public`** in your MainClass :

Locate your Form designer file (the one containing the declaration of all the controls of your Form) and change each declaration to Public.

```
Private pictureBox1 As Picturebox
' becomes
Public pictureBox1 As Picturebox
```

(Or just click on a control in the IDE, and change its accessibility level to Public)

Then if you can pass a variable pointing to an instance of `MainClass` in an instance of `RemoteClass`, then, through `RemoteClass`, you can access `TheMainClassInstance.pictureBox1`, and change its size, location, etc. everything.

Then how to create an instance of MainClass in RemoteClass ? It depends on the structure of your application... Without details, guess what.. we'll have to guess..!

```
Public Class RemoteClass
    Private _InstanceOfMainClass As MainClass = Nothing

    Public Sub New(ByRef NewInstanceOfMainClass As MainClass)
        _InstanceOfMainClass = NewInstanceOfMainClass
        ' ^^ this is one way doing it.
        ' ...
    End Sub
    ' ...

    Private Sub ChangeBackgroundColor()
        _InstanceOfMainClass.picturebox1.BackColor = Color.Black ' and voila !
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then you have a MainClass in your RemoteClass. Don't forget to dispose of _InstanceOfMainClass to avoid Memory Leak (I assume you know how to..)

---

How many instances of MainClass do you have ?
If it's just one, and you have several RemoteClass classes, then you could consider to make the member of MainClass you want to access as static (shared) members.

```
Public Class MainClass
    Private Shared _MyInstance As MainClass = Nothing

    Private Shared Sub InitializeMyInstance()
        If _MyInstance Is Nothing Then
            _MyInstance = New MainClass(...)
        Else
            If _MyInstance.IsDisposed Then
                ' Requires an IDisposable interface 
                ' and handling of Me.Closed event elsewhere...
                _MyInstance = Nothing
                _MyInstance = New MainClass(...)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property MyInstance() As MainClass
        Get
            InitializeMyInstance()
            Return _MyInstance
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property PictureBox1() As PictureBox
        Get
            Return MyInstance.pictureBox1
        End Get
    End Property

    ' Create as many Properties as required...

End Class
```

Then in ANY RemoteClass instance, you just call :

```
MainClass.PictureBox1.Width = 400
MainClass.Close()
MainClass.PictureBox1.Height = 200
```

But as I said, this works only if you only have a single instance of MainClass.

---

If you have several MainClass instances and several RemoteClass instances, consider using Unique IDs and a static function/property to access a specific instance.

How to create an ID ?

```
Public Class MainClass
    Private Shared _NextID As Integer = 0
    Private _ID As Integer

    Public ReadOnly Property ID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _ID
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(...)
        Me.InitializeComponents()
        ' ...
        _ID = _NextID
        _NextID = _NextID + 1
    End Sub

    ' ...
End Class
```

Then... Create a sorted list containing all the IDs :

```
Public Class MainClass

    Private Shared _IDsList As New SortedList(Of Integer, MainClass)

    ' then edit your New() method :
    Public Sub New(...)
        Me.InitializeComponents()
        ' ...
        _ID = _NextID
        _NextID = _NextID + 1
        _IDList.Add(_ID, Me)
    End Sub

    ' ...
End Class
```

Then create a static function to get a specific instance of MainClass by its ID.

```
Public Class MainClass

    ' ...

    Public Shared Function GetInstanceByID(ByVal iID As Integer) As MainClass
        If _IDList.ContainsKey(iID) Then
            Return _IDList.Item(iID)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

    ' ...

    ' And create the appropriate Dispose() method
    ' the appropriate Clear() method
    ' the appropriate FormClosing events handlers
    ' etc. etc. etc.

End Sub
```

the thing is, we don't know what's the purpose of your MainClass, and why RemoteClass instances have to modify MainClass members (*which* members by the way ? controls, variables, add/remove controls ?)

Comment: I would prefer using Region, haven't known it yet before you answered, and nice of you for such effort to give options to my question, I might use the other methods later... Keep it Up! Thanks!